# concurrent run using ListBlockingQueue thread is getting blocked for some reason

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

currently, I'm working on a Projekt where I have to make a simple program using `Threads` and `BlockingQueue` :

The program is Caesar encoding why the `LinkedBlockingQueue` well because it's an assignment :).

The Program shall read the letters from the console (including the Carriage return and the line feed `char(10)` `char(13)`) which will act as a flag to identify where the not-encoded letters end!.

so the queue would look something like this (assuming the shift factor is 3):

- `['a'->'a'->'a'->'13'->'d'->'d'->'d']`
- then while encoding the letter that is being read will get written in the encode queue and removed from the letters queue.

so what I did is the following:

**CODE:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class Caesar {
   private final static int CR = 13,LF=10, SHIFT_FACTOR=3, OFFSET=23;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        var br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        var letters = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Character>();

        var encoded = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Character>();
        var done = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Boolean>();

        Thread t1=new Thread(()-> takeInput(letters,br));
        Thread t2=new Thread(()->encode(letters,encoded));
        Thread t3=new Thread(()-> send(encoded,done));
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();
        t1.join();
        t2.join();
        t3.join();
        System.out.println(done.take());

    }

    private static void takeInput(BlockingQueue<Character>letters, BufferedReader br ) {
        System.out.println("Enter your input!.");
        int temp;
        try {
            while((temp=br.read())!=-1) {
                letters.put((char) temp);
                System.out.println("added "+ temp+ " and letters queue is "+letters);
                if (temp == CR || temp == LF){

                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch (IOException | InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        finally {
            try {
                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        }
    }

    public static void encode(BlockingQueue<Character>letters, BlockingQueue<Character>encoded) {

        try {
            char tempLetter;
            while(!letters.isEmpty()){//dont know why its not going in here!!!! BLOCKED HERE debugger dont want to get in here!
                System.out.println("inside encode");
                tempLetter=letters.take();
                if (tempLetter == CR ||tempLetter ==LF){
                    encoded.put(tempLetter);
                    break;
                }else if (tempLetter == ' ' || tempLetter == '.') {
                    encoded.put(tempLetter);
                }else if (cap(tempLetter) < 'X') {
                    encoded.put((char)(tempLetter+SHIFT_FACTOR));/
                }else{
                    encoded.put((char)(tempLetter - OFFSET));
                }
            }
        }catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    private static Character cap(Character temp) {
        return temp >= 'a' ? Character.toUpperCase(temp):temp;/
    }

    private static void send( BlockingQueue<Character> encoded, BlockingQueue<Boolean> done){
        try {
            char temp=encoded.take();
            while (!encoded.isEmpty()){
                System.out.println("stuck in encode!");
                if(temp==CR || temp==LF)
                    break;
                System.out.print(temp);
                temp=encoded.take();
            }
            done.put(true);
        }catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Desired OUTPUT**

```
Enter your input!.
aaaa
started encoding
the encoded elements are : -> dddd
```

**The output I'm getting: !**

```
Enter your input!.
aaa
added 97 and letters queue is [a]
added 97 and letters queue is [a, a]
added 97 and letters queue is [a, a, a]
added 10 and letters queue is [a, a, a, 
]

(the program is on hold without and doesn't want to enter the while loop in the encrypt!!!!)
```

The prof gave us a GO code to use it as Reference to be able to realize the functions :

here is a link to the go code on [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/hUpg5nYm)

feel free to suggest anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The solution**

Mainly, I had to correct the loop condition and use each of `take()`, `put()` , `offer()` correctly.

plus, benefiting from the advice of the user @Andy Turner of not using Iterators nor enhanced for loops.

Further reference for learning the LinkedBlockingQueue:

- [LinkedBlockingQueue.html#iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingQueue.html#iterator())
- [Interface BlockingQueue Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
- [Java BlockingQueue tutorials jenkov](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html)
- [GeekForGeek BlockingQueue Interface in Java](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/blockingqueue-interface-in-java/)

the methods look like this now:

```
private static void encode(BlockingQueue<Character>letters,BlockingQueue<Character> encoded) {
    System.out.println("started encoding");
    try {
        char toEncode;
        while (true) {
            toEncode=letters.take();
            if (toEncode == ' ' || toEncode == '.'){
                encoded.offer(toEncode);
            }else if (toEncode == CR ||toEncode ==LF){
                encoded.offer(toEncode);
                break;//reached our flag!.
            }else if (cap(toEncode) < 'X') {
                encoded.offer((char)(toEncode+SHIFT_FACTOR));
            }else{
                encoded.offer((char)(toEncode - OFFSET));
            }
        }
   } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}

private static void send( BlockingQueue<Character> encoded, BlockingQueue<Boolean> done){
    try {
        char temp;
        while(true){
            temp=encoded.take();
            if (temp==CR || temp==LF)
                break;
            System.out.print(temp);
        }
        System.out.println();
        done.offer(true);//no need to use put() though.
    } catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
    t1.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.start();
    t2.join();
    t3.start();
    t3.join();
```

You start a thread, then wait for it to finish before starting the next.

Put all the joins after the starts:

```
    t1.start();
    t2.start();
    t3.start();
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
```

Comment: please look up the edit i added. this will make the program to work wrongly

Comment: @studentaccount4 you will need to provide more detail than "will make the program behave wrongly". I suspect the problem you're having is because of trying to iterate the queue using an enhanced for loop, especially in multiple threads.

Comment: sorry i just added it :)

Comment: please feel free to advise me what is happening :)

Comment: @studentaccount4 I would suggest reading the Javadoc of [`LinkedBlockingDeque.iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html#iterator()).

Comment: would you please enlighten me how would the use of iterator solve the wrongly behavior of the program?!

Comment: @studentaccount4 enhanced for loops use iterators. Your threads all start at (roughly) the same time; given what it says in the Javadoc, and what is in the queue when the iterators are created, what are the second and third threads' enhanced for loops likely to do?

Comment: @studentaccount4 (hint: you don't want to use enhanced for loops at all).

Comment: sir i already tried to use iterator in each of the Send and the encode methods but this didnt solve the problem :)

Comment: @studentaccount4 the reason I say you shouldn't be using enhanced for loops is *because* they use iterators, and the reason not to use iterators is described in the Javadoc. You don't want to be doing anything that uses iterators, explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: please take a look i followed your suggestion and got feedback from the professor about using an additional `BlockingQueue` to add the `done` boolean.